# Spark sql extensions with multiple extensions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I want to specify multiple extensions with `spark.sql.extensions` configuration of Spark 3.0.

But it overrides the previous extension with the new ones. As per the Spark 3.0 docs, we can use comma separated list of extensions but its not working. Comma separated list of extension do not take any use.

Do we have any another configuration by which we can set multiple extensions OR is there any another way to set?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a comma-separated list. From [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSessionExtensions.scala):

```
  * The extensions can also be used by setting the Spark SQL configuration property
  * `spark.sql.extensions`. Multiple extensions can be set using a comma-separated list. For example:
  * {{{
  *   SparkSession.builder()
  *     .master("...")
  *     .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.example.MyExtensions,org.example.YourExtensions")
  *     .getOrCreate()
```

I have this set up through PySpark and also through AWS EMR's command-runner.jar, works in both.